# Эффект css - Как сделать текст полупрозрачным, когда он выходит за границы блока?

Tags: css, css3

Как добиться такого эффекта, когда текст выходит за границы блока?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.divs { overflow:hidden; height:100px; }
.divs p { /*  style of the text  */ }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
div {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  font: 400 17px sans-serif;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
    rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,
    rgba(255,255,255,.8) 20%,
    rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example Example 
</div>
```